# Error: pandas hashtable keyerror

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have successfully read a csv file using pandas. When I am trying to print the a particular column from the data frame i am getting keyerror. Hereby i am sharing the code with the error.

```
import pandas as pd
reviews_new = pd.read_csv("D:\\aviva.csv")
reviews_new['review']
```

**

```
reviews_new['review']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-43-ed485b439a1c>", line 1, in <module>
    reviews_new['review']
  File "C:\Users\30216\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1997, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Users\30216\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2004, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Users\30216\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1350, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Users\30216\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3290, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Users\30216\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1947, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)
KeyError: 'review'
```

**

Can someone help me in this ?

Comment: What is `print (reviews_new.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: what does the original csv actually look like? What does `print(reviews_new.columns.tolist())` show? You may have spaces in your col names

Comment: Please share the output of `reviews_new.info()`

Comment: You have to provide column names if they are not present in the csv. Please paste output of reviews_new.columns

Comment: @ jezrael & edchum :                                                                             print (reviews_new.columns.tolist())
['Name', ' Date', ' review']

Comment: @ayhan : <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 180 entries, 0 to 179
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Name       180 non-null object
 Date      180 non-null object
 review    180 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 4.3+ KB

Comment: @AbhinavKarthick like EdChum and jezrael said, you have white space in front of the column name.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think first is best investigate, what are real columns names, if convert to list better are seen some whitespaces or similar:

```
print (reviews_new.columns.tolist())
```

---

I think there can be 2 problems (obviously):

**1.whitespaces in columns names (maybe in data also)**

Solutions are [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) whitespaces in column names:

```
reviews_new.columns = reviews_new.columns.str.strip()
```

Or add parameter `skipinitialspace` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
reviews_new = pd.read_csv("D:\\aviva.csv", skipinitialspace=True)
```

**2.different separator as default `,`**

Solution is add parameter `sep`:

```
#sep is ;
reviews_new = pd.read_csv("D:\\aviva.csv", sep=';')
#sep is whitespace
reviews_new = pd.read_csv("D:\\aviva.csv", sep='\s+')
reviews_new = pd.read_csv("D:\\aviva.csv", delim_whitespace=True)
```

EDIT:

You get whitespace in column name, so need `1.solutions`:

```
print (reviews_new.columns.tolist())
['Name', ' Date', ' review'] 
          ^        ^
```

EDIT1:

If no column name if test `print (df.columns.tolist())` and faile select first 'column' of DataFrame solution is select `df.index`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':list('abc'),
                   'col1':list('efg'),
                   'col2':range(3)}).set_index('col1')

print (df)
     col  col2
col1          
e      a     0
f      b     1
g      c     2


print (df.columns.tolist())
['col', 'col2']

print (df.index)
Index(['e', 'f', 'g'], dtype='object', name='col1')

print (df.index.get_level_values('col1'))
Index(['e', 'f', 'g'], dtype='object', name='col1')
```

If there is MultiIndex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':list('abc'),
                   'col1':list('efg'),
                   'col2':range(3)}).set_index(['col1', 'col'])

print (df)
          col2
col1 col      
e    a       0
f    b       1
g    c       2

print (df.index)
MultiIndex([('e', 'a'),
            ('f', 'b'),
            ('g', 'c')],
           names=['col1', 'col'])

print (df.index.get_level_values('col1'))
Index(['e', 'f', 'g'], dtype='object', name='col1')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("file.txt", skipinitialspace=True)
df.head()
df['review']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dfObj['Hash Key'] = (dfObj['DEAL_ID'].map(str) +dfObj['COST_CODE'].map(str) +dfObj['TRADE_ID'].map(str)).apply(hash)

#for index, row in dfObj.iterrows():
#        dfObj.loc[`enter code here`index,'hash'] = hashlib.md5(str(row[['COST_CODE','TRADE_ID']].values)).hexdigest()

print(dfObj['hash'])
```