# How to figure out this Python Exception

Tags: python

I am totally lost with this one and have absolutely no idea how to approach this issue.

**Background**

I have programmed a little application with a TK frontend. It does read three csv reports and aggregates them into one. All of them are processed on my machine. A colleague of mine has been using this app for a while now, also without any issues until four weeks ago. Whenever the third reports is being processed the following feedback is displayed:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1945, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)
KeyError: 'EXTENSION'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\username\BillingEngine_2\Python files\GUI.py", line 148, in <lambda>
    command=lambda: run_merge_engineering_reports())
  File "C:\Users\username\BillingEngine_2\Python files\GUI.py", line 28, in run_merge_engineering_reports
    er_Switzerland = read_files.read_special_countries_er(base_dir, ",", "Switzerland")
  File "C:\Users\username\BillingEngine_2\Python files\read_files.py", line 47, in read_special_countries_er
    print("There are", engineering_data["EXTENSION"].count(), "extensions from the Engineering Report in\n", fullpath)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1997, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2004, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1350, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3290, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1947, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)
KeyError: 'EXTENSION'
```

This goes way beyond of what I know about programming and I am therefore asking for help or at least an initial hint.

**What we have checked so far**

Of course we were trying the obvious:

- Do we have the exact same reports we want to process?
- Do we have the same Python files (same version)?
- Do we use the same Python (latest Anaconda environment)?

We can answer "yes" to every single one (checked via webex, as my colleague sits abroad). The only thing that we cannot ensure is that the machines are exactly the same. But it all worked until four weeks ago and all that we know, there were not any fundamental changes.

**What I thought to understand**

It seems to indicate that it cannot find the column 'EXTENSION' (KeyError). But it is definitely there and on my machine it processes it with no issue.

Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: I would probably first look to see if it's actually now `'EXTENSION '` or similar i.e. trailing whitespace.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736163/error-pandas-hashtable-keyerror see solutions there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: pandas hashtable keyerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43736163/error-pandas-hashtable-keyerror)

Comment: The way to debug starts with `print(engineering_data.head())` after reading the csv in, or write the df head back to a csv (`engineering_data.head(50).to_csv("check_me.csv")`), and check that the column titles and data it contains match your expectations.

Comment: In the [exception handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), print or log the DataFrame columns and the variable that references the column name for comparison.

Comment: While I will check all the hints / links once I am back to work on Monday, there is one thing that bugs me: All of this runs perfectly fine on my machine. Why would it ignore possible whitespace / non-standard-separator on my machine, but not on my colleague's one?