# Modify one column values based on multiple conditions of another column

Tags: python, pandas

If I have the following dataframe. I want to return arbitrary values for column B based on multiple conditions of column A, here is the rules: if values in column A >= 0 and < 50, return original values of columns B; if values in column A >= 50 and < 70, return values of columns B divided by 3; if values in column A >= 70 and < 100, return return values of columns B divided by column C and 3.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
```

My pseudocode in Python:

```
def Standard():
    if (df['A'] >= 0) and (df['A'] < 50):
        return df['B'] 
    if (df['A'] >= 50) and (df['A'] < 70):
        return df['B']/3
    if (df['A'] >= 70) and (df['A'] <= 100):
        return df['B']/df['C']/3

df['B'] = df.apply(Standard, axis = 1)
```

It returns: `TypeError: ('Standard() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given', 'occurred at index 0')`

How could I correct my code or if there are other better methods in Python? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For better performance use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) instead `apply`, also is possible set default value if not match any condition:

```
masks = [(df['A'] >= 0) & (df['A'] < 50),
         (df['A'] >= 50) & (df['A'] < 70),
         (df['A'] >= 70) & (df['A'] <= 100)]

vals = [df['B'], df['B'] / 3, df['B']/df['C']/3]

df['B'] = np.select(masks, vals, default=0)
```

**Performance** - It is about 1000 times faster:

```
np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(10000, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))

#Jeril solution
In [74]: %timeit df['B1'] = df.apply(Standard, axis=1)
__main__:18: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
424 ms ± 16.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [75]: %timeit df['B'] = np.select(masks, vals, default=0)
468 µs ± 4.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: I get `KeyError: 'A'`, any ideas how to deal with this ? Thanks.

Comment: @ahbon - What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: There are `None` inside, maybe problem come from this?

Comment: @ahbon - Do you think column name is `None`? Because keyerror means there is no column `A` - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43736163)

Comment: No, I don't think columns name error, I think maybe cause from `nan`, `None` in column `A`, maybe I was wrong. Another problem: based on conditions, I need to multiply column `A` by `100` then divide by values of column `B` and then divide by `30`, but all result become `0.0`, i used this code: `df['A'].mul(10).div(df['B'], axis = 0).div(30)`.

Comment: I can't figure out why all become `0`s, if i calculate manually, they aren't `0`s.

Comment: @ahbon - I think there should be problem with NaNs, if use `df[['A','B']] = df[['A','B']].fillna(0)` it working? Because NaNs should be alo in `B` column.

Comment: No, it doesn't work out, the values of `df['A']` is either becomes `0.0`s or `NaN`s.

Comment: @ahbon - Are data of these 2 columns confidental?

Comment: Not really, I can send you some examples.

Comment: @ahbon - Super, you can sent it to my email in my profile (run code for get email address)

Comment: Just send u by email, please check, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the following:

```
def Standard(row):
    if (row['A'] >= 0) and (row['A'] < 50):
        return row['B']
    if (row['A'] >= 50) and (row['A'] < 70):
        return row['B']/3
    if (row['A'] >= 70) and (row['A'] <= 100):
        return row['B']/row['C']/3


df['B'] = df.apply(Standard, axis=1)
```