# Read DataFrame from .csv file, column not recognized

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, series

I'm using the following code to import data from [this csv file](https://github.com/jacktator/QuantTrading_Py/blob/master/data/gen/usAXP_df.csv) into pandas `DataFrame`. And I expect to get a `Series` data, however I get an error instead.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('../../data/gen/the_file.csv'.format(symbol),
                 parse_dates=True,
                 index_col=0)
df.info()

close_series = df.close
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 392 entries, 2017-06-12 to 2018-12-31
Data columns (total 12 columns):
close                    392 non-null float64
high                     392 non-null float64
low                      392 non-null float64
p_change                 392 non-null float64
open                     392 non-null float64
pre_close                392 non-null float64
volume                   392 non-null int64
date                     392 non-null int64
date_week                392 non-null int64
key                      392 non-null int64
atr21                    392 non-null float64
atr14                    392 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(8), int64(4)
memory usage: 39.8 KB

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: @MohamedThasinah A typo. Just fixed it.

Comment: use `df['close']`. recommended `df['close'].copy()`

Comment: if mohammed advise does not work, try to get the column names: `df.columns.values`

Comment: @MohamedThasinah I've tried that too, got `KeyError: 'close'` error

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: Maybe help [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43736163)

Comment: @jezrael `['close ', 'high              ', 'low               ', 'p_change             ', 'open  ', 'pre_close', 'volume  ', 'date    ', 'date_week', 'key', 'atr21             ', 'atr14']`

Comment: so use `df['close ']`

Comment: remove trailing space or use df['close ']

Comment: if you have it more in your code, oyu can rename the column: `df.rename(columns={'close ': 'close'}, inplace=True)`

Comment: to remove spaces in column I use this,

`s= [col.strip() for col in df.columns.tolist()]
df.columns = s`