# Plot Irregular time Series Data and techniques for prediction

Tags: python, time-series

I am trying to plot my dataset which has different dates and a variable.My dataset looks like :

```
Date          var
2018-08-01  0.002312
2018-08-02  0.002320
2018-08-04  0.002312
2018-08-13  0.002318
2018-08-14  0.002315
```

Dataset has a total of 168 values and I want to predict for a period of next 30 days.

Part-1

I am trying to plot the values on the graph using the following code :

```
df1.pivot('Date', 'var').plot()
```

I am getting this error

> File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>
> KeyError: 'Date'

Can anyone help me with the same.

Part-2

I am planning to forecast the variable var for next 30 days or so. I know that certain imputations need to be done. Can anyone advise some suggested pointers for how to impute the values and best algorithm for predicting the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The actual header name is `Date.` so try: `df1.pivot('Date.', 'var').plot()`

Comment: @TomasRuiz My apologies, its Date only... Putting up on stackoverflow has changed it, edited the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this for part one:

First, we create the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
Date = ['2018-08-01', '2018-08-02', '2018-08-04', '2018-08-13']
var = [0.002312,0.002320, 0.002312, 0.002318]
frame = pd.DataFrame({'Date': Date,
                     'var': var})
```

The output looks like this:

```
    Date        var
0   2018-08-01  0.002312
1   2018-08-02  0.002320
2   2018-08-04  0.002312
3   2018-08-13  0.002318
```

Then we plot it with this code and imports:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
frame.plot('Date', 'var')
```

It will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi there, utilize only df1.plot() or make sure that the variable names match i.e. df1.plot('FDate', 'var') not df1.plot('FlightDate', 'Rate'). Should you want those names displayed on your graph, you need to rename the column headers in the dataframe.

Comment: You could also rename the x and y axes labels with the imported matplotlib using plt.xlabel('FlightDate') and plt.ylabel('Rate').

Comment: I am sorry for this mistake.. although I am using Date and Rate and still getting the same error 

`df1.plot(Date', 'var')`

Comment: See this question answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/43736331/10407409 - It could be there are whitespaces in your column name or the delimiter being different.

Comment: Can you please take a look at it

Comment: Yes I can. Please share the code of the creation of the df dataframe as well as the output of the following code: df.columns

Comment: I am not able to upload the CSV but here is what I am doing... 

`df = pd.read_csv('outfile.csv')
df.columns = ['Date','var']
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df = df.set_index('Date').groupby('Date').mean() # Group Dates as 1 result.
df.plot('Date','var')`

Comment: Wow, it's difficult for me from here onwards to try and isolate the issue. You can print the dataframe right? df.head(). Also, it could be a typo but earlier you left out a ' in your code df1.plot(Date', 'var') - it should be df1.plot('Date', 'var').

Comment: Hi @The Orchestrator I somehow restarted my system and it worked for me... Weird problem but it worked... Thanks a lot for the help!!!

Comment: That's great news @user3759616 and you're welcome. Please feel free to upvote some of my comments :). Keep well